# How to apply :hover on :after to certain div in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Made an in-depth search and learnt on how to create some stylish custom created textboxes to achieve a better graphic look. I have two issues to complete this mesh-up of textboxes so that they serve a total functioning of a common textbox.

1. I'm unable to execute the :focus on the parent div container, although the code is perfectly fine in CSS because when going by **Inspect Element (Chrome)**, **Force Element to> :focus** it does what I want but in the real-time it never does nevertheless clicking on its children or itself.
2. I want to add the **:hover** effect on the child div container (*the left black coloured div*) in which it'll expand the **:after** transition for a certain amount of pixels (*assuming +20px/+30px*).

The desired and the final result should look like in the picture below:
[image: Custom textfield issues]

```
#submitForm {
    border:2px grey inset;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:table;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
    width: 800px;
}
#submitForm #btnSend {
    bottom:20px;
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    right: 20px;
    width:100px;
}
#submitForm .highlights {
    border-bottom:5px solid #2E8DEF;
    border-radius:15px;
    float:left;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width: 520px;
}
#submitForm .highlights:focus {
    border-bottom:none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(105, 185, 250, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(105, 185, 250, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(105, 185, 250, 0.8);
}
#submitForm .tags, #submitForm .textarea {
    float:left;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
#submitForm .tags {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    background: #333333;
    color: #2E8DEF;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    z-index:3;
}
#submitForm .tags:after {
    background: #333333;
    content:" ";
    display: block;
    left: 90px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
    z-index:-1;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
#submitForm .tags:hover {
    text-shadow: #2E8DEF 0px 0px 5px;
}
#submitForm .tags:after:hover {
    /* Code for expanding the skewed  .tags:after */
}
#submitForm .textarea {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    appearance: field;
    -moz-appearance: field;
    -webkit-appearance: field;
}
#submitForm .textarea:focus {
    outline:0;
}

<forms id='submitForm'>
    <div id='formName' class='highlights'>
        <div class='tags'>Name</div>
        <div class='textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
    <div id='formSurname' class='highlights'>
        <div class='tags'>Surname</div>
        <div class='textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
    <div id='formAddress'class='highlights'>
        <div class='tags'>Address</div>
        <div class='textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
    <div id='formCity' class='highlights'>
        <div class='tags'>City</div>
        <div class='textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
    <div id='formPhone' class='highlights'>
        <div class='tags'>Phone</div>
        <div class='textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
    <button id="btnSend" type="button" onclick='submitListOfProducts()'>Submit</button>
</forms>
```

And, the link to JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xa3nwhj4/1/

Comment: Not really I already tried that option, but I'm trying to append a highlight on the outer div (parent one, with classname 'highlights') so that entire bracket gets bordered with good rendered shadow effect, not just the inner child one.

Comment: Just a minor suggestion: `#submitForm .highlights { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vishal provided the reason for the hover effect not working - this is my addition to it:
- focus only fires on the textarea, but you want to change the style of the parent div

so lets change the css entry for `#submitForm .highlights:focus` to `#submitForm .focusedhighlights`

and then let jquery do the magic:

```
$(".textarea").focus(function(){ //event handler, to fire when a textarea gets focused
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("focusedhighlights") //toggle class on parent element for highlight effect
});

$(".textarea").focusout(function(){ //event handler to fire, when textarea gets unfocused
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("focusedhighlights") // toggle class to remove highlight effect
});
```

see working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vo59rgnd/2/

Comment: Here is the final solution combined with both 3 comments given by you guys. And I'm very thankful to you that I finally finished this beautiful tool. Gonna accept Errand's solution as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The `:focus` is not working because you are adding focus to `.highlights` which is a `<div>` and not `input element`.

And to expand the `onhover`. The CSS should be like this

```
#submitForm .tags:hover {
    text-shadow: #2E8DEF 0px 0px 5px;
    width:160px;
}
#submitForm .tags:hover:after {
    left:130px;
}
```

See the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Lrdmuzu6/